# Show a continuous function on a closed bounded interval is Lipschitz under the maximum (infinity) norm

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness, normed-spaces, lipschitz-functions

I'm currently working on the following:

> Define the function $\psi: C[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ by $\begin{equation*} \psi(f)=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx \end{equation*}$ for each $f \in C[a,b]$. 
>   Show that $\psi$ is Lipschitz on $C[a,b]$ with the metric induced by the maximum norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{\infty}$.

So, what we want to show is $\Vert \psi(f) -\psi(g)\Vert_{\infty} \leq c\Vert f-g \Vert_{\infty}$.

Now, $\Vert \psi(f) - \psi(g) \Vert_{\infty}=\Vert \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx - \int_{a}^{b}g(x)dx\Vert_{\infty} = \Vert \int_{a}^{b}f(x)-g(x)\,dx\Vert_{\infty}$

And this is about as far as I got. Maybe it's working with the maximum norms, but I am having great difficulty figuring out how to turn this into something resembling $\leq c \Vert f-g \Vert_{\infty}$.

I'm wondering if I can use uniform continuity to help me, since $f$ is mapping a compact metric space into a metric space.

Please Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing stuff up.

The functional $\psi$ takes values in $\mathbb{R}$, so start with
$|\psi(f)-\psi(g)|$ and use the fact that $|\int h| \le \int |h|$.

Then use the fact that $|h(x)| \le \|h\|_\infty$ for all $x$.

In the above, $h(x) = f(x)-g(x)$.

Explicitly:

\begin{eqnarray}
|\psi(f)-\psi(g)| &=& |\int_a^b (f(x)-g(x)) dx | \\
&\le& \int_a^b |f(x)-g(x)| dx \\
&\le& \int_a^b \| f-g\|_\infty dx \\
&=& (b-a) \| f-g\|_\infty
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go! Is $|h(x)| \leq \Vert h\Vert_{\infty}$ b/c the norms are equivalent? (We showed that earlier in the course)

Comment: No. It is because of the definition. $\|h\|_\infty = \max_{x \in [a,b]} |h(x)|$. I have not introduced any other norm here?

Comment: no, of course not. My bad. Thanks.

Comment: once I've gotten to the point that $\vert \int f - g \vert \leq \int \vert f - g \vert$, then what? How do I get that this is $\leq |f-g|$ times a nonnegative constant?  I'm a little lost at this point.

Comment: I have added an explicit proof. I am just fleshing out the hints I gave.

Comment: I realized it hadn't completely answered my question. Sorry - I'll re-accept. Aren't $f$ and $g$ functions of $x$, though? Why are you able to treat the maximum norm like a constant in that integral?

Comment: If $f,g$ are given, then $\|f-g\|_\infty$ is just a number, it doesn't depend on $x$.

Comment: very clever! Thanks a lot!